# Unity Transform Point returns wrong value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I have this hierarchy:

```
ScriptHandler <= this have script

MultiShape <= taking sides[] from here 
     local_axis_1 <= I need Global coordinates of this
     local_axis_2 <= side[i] have this as GameObject field 
          Projectile1 
          Projectile2
```

Im need to TransformPoint, for get location of localAxises in global coordinates. But all, what i trying to do fails: check code.

So how to get global position of this gameObject?

some guys recommending make this: sides[i].transform.parent.TransformPoint(sides[i].transform.position)

this thing works well, then MultiShape have rotation (0,0,0). But then i change rotation of z, its dont working.

```
//this dont work anytime, even rotation is 0,0,0
ShapeSide[] sides = mainMesh.shapeSides;
Vector3 pos = sides[i].localAxis.transform.TransformPoint(sides[i].localAxis.transform.position);

//this works only then rotation is 0,0,0
ShapeSide[] sides = mainMesh.shapeSides;
Vector3 pos = sides[i].localAxis.transform.parent.TransformPoint(sides[i].localAxis.transform.position);
```

Comment: `transform.position` is already global position.

Comment: @Draco18s lol its really works..... send a answer, im choose it

Answer (score 1):

[`Transform.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) is already global position

> The world space position of the Transform.

There is no reason to transform this value from local to world space.